# How would I get this to print out the equation rather than calculate

Tags: java

The assignment is to write a method called fractionSum that accepts an integer parameter n and returns as a double the sum of the first n terms of the sequence: 1 + (1/2) + (1/3) + (1/4) + (1/5) + ...+(1/n) You may assume that the parameter n is non-negative.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fraction { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int a = console.nextInt();

        fractionSum(a);
    }

    public static void fractionSum (int a) {
        for(int i = 1; i<=a; i++) { 
        double sum = (1/i);
        System.out.println(sum);
        } 
    }
}
```

What it does right now is just calculate the actual value

How would I get it to print out "1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n"

Comment: "What it does right now is just calculate the actual value." Are you sure about that?  Because what you posted will print a 1, followed by `a-1` zeroes.

Comment: If you want to calculate a **sum** then you need to have some **addition** involved.

Comment: This question should be closed.  It's not exactly a duplicate of the question @MichaelPetrotta is posting... but it's obvious that that question solved a problem he was having with his homework and he turned around and immediately posted the next part, clearly putting zero effort into first attempting to solve the problem on his own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tested and works:**

```
public static void fractionSum (int a) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) 
    {
        if (i != 1)
            System.out.print(" + 1/" + i);
        else 
            System.out.print("1");
    } 
}
```

Comment: `double sum = (1/i);` Why didn't you fix it as well?

Comment: @PM77-1 forgot. thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void fractionSum (int a) {
        System.out.print("1");
        double sum = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i<=a; i++) { 
            System.out.print(" + 1/" + i);
            sum += (1/(double)i);
        } 
        System.out.print("/n" + sum);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile it?

Comment: I'm certain it works.

Comment: And does it calculate the **sum**?

Comment: oops =o figured his code was fixed from the last question. edited